# Processing ASCII-character with regular expression

Tags: c++, regex

There is a raw array of unsigned char, full of different symbols [0, 255].

I need to find and extract some string "01", specify a regular expression. Code looks like work, but it doesn't find the string that i need and i do not understand what the problem is.

```
stringstream rawString;

for (unsigned char i=0; i<255; i++) {
    rawString << i;
}

regex pattern("[\\x00-\\xff]*(01)[\\x00-\\xff]*", regex_constants::egrep);
smatch result;

if ( regex_match( rawString.str(), result, pattern ) ) {
    cout << result[1];
}
```

Comment: add an input and output of what you want parsed from regex thanks :)

Comment: what is 'rawString'? Also, C++11 has this std::regex. That would be nicer than low-level C functions. :)

Comment: input - for (unsigned char i=0; i<255; i++) {
    rawString << i;
}

and i need to find "01" string

Comment: Please describe, "doesn't work".  What input are you giving it, and what output are you getting?

Comment: input: all characters [0; 255] in rawString; 

output: i need to find "01" in rawString

Comment: You've said what output you want, but you haven't said what output you are getting.

Comment: regex_match returns false

Answer (score 1):

The very first character you store is a zero, a.k.a. the standard string *terminator*. So your regex finds this character as the very first one and (correctly) says it's done.

Comment: Hmm. You are also putting literal zeros inside your regex -- that could be the same problem. regex is really meant for processing binary text, it is designed to handle plain text only.

Comment: Sorry -- "literal zeros" is not true. Have you tried your expression on a *simple* test case, to make sure it works at all? if it does, then the problem lies in your input. If it doesn't ..

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are overkill for this simple search.

```
std::string::size_type loc = 0;
while ((loc = my_string.find("01", loc)) != std::string::npos) {
    std::cout << "Found at: " << loc << '\n';
    ++loc;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but example that i had posted just a model of real task. I'm getting raw C-string (filled out raw bytes) and i need to find some substring given regular expression in that C-string. Moreover, the user sets regular expression dynamically.

Comment: @nullptr - that's a drawback of simplifying a problem in order to post it. In your question, though, you say that you're searching for `"0`"`; you might want to change that to more clearly state what the real question is.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char rawString[256];

for (int i=0; i<256; i++) {
    rawString[i] = i;
}

string str(rawString, rawString + sizeof(rawString));

regex pattern("^([^\\x00]|[\\x00])*(01)([^\\x00]|[\\x00])*$");
smatch result;

if ( regex_match( str, result, pattern ) ) {
    cout << result[2];
}
```

Comment: i have found the solution